# Using commons digester how do I parse a single xml entry into multiple fields in an object?

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

How do I map "Joe Smith" to first name "Joe" last name "Smith"?

I already have code to split up the name, I'm not sure how to make that work with the Digester though.

```
<guestlist>
  <guest>
   <name>Joe Smith</name>
  </guest>
</guestlist>

public class Guest(){
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy answer is: add an additional property to your Guest class:

```
public class Guest {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public void setBothNames(String bothNames) {
        String[] split = bothNames.split(" ");
        firstName = split[0];
        lastName = split[1];
    }
```

and the bean property setter rule to the digester:

```
    digester.addBeanPropertySetter("guestlist/guest/name", "bothNames");
```

Comment: This would work, but It's not ideal. I'm looking for more of a plugin or converter or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Loading from a file, you can also load from a stream
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Guests.xml");


// Query the data and write out a subset of guests

var guests= from c in loaded.Descendants("guest")
        select new
        {
            FirstName = SplitFunc_FirstName(c.Element("name")),
            LastName = SplitFunc_LastName(c.Element("name"))
        };

foreach (var guest in guests)
{
    Your custom code...to attach it to your entity object.
}
```

Note: SplitFunc_FirstName is your custom function which you already wrote to extact first and last name.

Comment: This is neither in Java nor using Commons Digester.

Comment: Hi ChssPly76, This is in C# 3.0 using LinqToXML and Anonymous Types.

Comment: Did not noticed the "commons digester", that was the reason for C# solution.